# finite additive measures question

Tags: measure-theory

Let Ω be a countable set and F the collection of all its subsets. Put
µ(A) = 0 if A is finite and µ(A) = ∞ if A is infinite. Show that the set function µ is
finitely additive but not σ-additive.

Does anyone know how to answer this? i feel like you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\Omega$ is countable, write $\Omega=\{a_{1},a_{2},\ldots\}$. If $A_{1},\ldots,A_{n}$ are finite subsets of $\Omega$, which are disjoint, then $A=\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\bigcup}A_{i}$ is finite. Hence,

$$
\mu(A)=0=\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}\mu(A_{i}).
$$

Thus, $\mu$ is finitely additive. To see that it is not $\sigma$-additive, let $B_{i}=\{a_{i}\}$ for $i\geq 1$. Let $B=\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\bigcup}B_{i}$. The $B_{i}$'s are disjoint, but since $B$ is infinite, we have

$$
\mu(B)=\infty\not=0=\sum_{1\leq i\leq n}\mu(B_{i}).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is one case for finite additivity:

If $A_1,\dots,A_N$ are all finite sets, then $\mu(A_n)=0$ for all n. Also, $\bigcup_n A_n$ is finite, so $\mu(\bigcup_n A_n)=0$. Therefore $\sum_n \mu(A_n) = \mu(\bigcup_n A_n)$